# NoSuchMethod Exception

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, bluetooth-lowenergy, nosuchmethoderror

I was using `BLE startLescan` but its now obsolete. Now I have changed my API `level to 23 (from 20)` and using `BluetoothLeScanner` for the purpose.
My start scan function is:

```
public void startScan(){
    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

     mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

                String s = "\nRssi : "+result.getRssi()+"" +
                        "\nName (Get Device) : "+result.getDevice().getName()+"" +
                        "\nBytes"+result.getScanRecord().getBytes()+"" +
                        "\nGet Device : " + result.getDevice()+"" +
                        "\nAddress : "+result.getDevice().getAddress()+"" +
                        "\nService UUIds : "+result.getScanRecord().getServiceUuids().get(0)+"" +       //Unique
                        "\nName (Scan Record) : "+result.getScanRecord().getDeviceName()+"" +
                        "\nUuids device : "+result.getDevice().getUuids()+"" +
                        "\nDescribe contents : "+result.describeContents();

                //This will show you all the data in logs.
                Log.e("All Data",s);



            }

            @Override
            public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
                super.onBatchScanResults(results);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            }
        });
```

When i reach the first line,

> java throws a nosuchmethod exception:
>
> method lookup failed for selector "getBluetoothLeScanner" with
>   signature "()Landroid/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner;"

Comment: show us the code above `startScan` method. How you are initializing `mBluetoothAdapter` ?/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your device has API version 20 or lower it won't be able to use the new API. So you need to implement both scan methods and check which version should be used, based on the devices os version. (Kitkat won't support the new scan API!)

Answer (score 1):

An instance of the BluetoothAdapter is required in this case. Do something like this:

```
Context mContext = getBaseContext();
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = (BluetoothManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE).getAdapter();
BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(new ScanCallback() {….

}
```

Comment: The bluetooth adapte is there, i instantiated it in the beginning:    BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);   
   mBluetoothAdapter = manager.getAdapter();